# Context free grammar L={$a^{m}$ $b^{n}$ $c^{k}$| n,m,k >= 0, n>= m+k}

Tags: context-free-grammar

Write a context free grammar for the following:

$$L=\{a^{m}b^{n}c^{k}\mid n,m,k \ge 0, n\ge m+k\}$$

I am having some trouble writing the above cfg from the language. So far I have:

$$\begin{align*}
S&\to S_1S_2S_3\\
S_1&\to aS_1b\\
S_1&\to \lambda\\
S_2&\to bS_2\\
S_2&\to \lambda\\
S_3&\to bS_3c\\
S_3&\to \lambda
\end{align*}$$

Am I oversimplifying this question or is it straight forward?

Comment: How does this set-up guarantee the number of b is not less than the sum of number of a and number of c? Maybe explaining that would improve the question...

Comment: This is a straightforward question and it seems like you're on the right track

Comment: Could you rewrite your question to use the proposed new rules? Your original grammar derives $abcbc$ but I can't tell if that's true of your revision.

Comment: Okay so I've rewrote the question using new rules @BrianO

Comment: @ImTheRealOne OK *that* is better.

Comment: Looks fine now.